# Are the route handlers in express called synchronously or asynchronously?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have two redirections in a `routes.js` file:

```
app.get('*', blockingController01);
app.get('/test', controller02);
```

The business is, that I have a 'blocking landing page' in which you have to enter a valid code to access to the rest of the site. `blockingController01` sends a rendered page with a form to enter the code. If user didn't enter the a correct code then if he/she enters '/test' or any other the page should redirect to the `insert code` page.

I tried to solve this just putting a controller for the code page at the beginning and covering all paths with the wildcard *. So i'm wondering two things:

1. Are the controllers that handle the same paths called asynchronously?
2. Does express have something to avoid to call the rest of the controllers?

Thanks!

Comment: As stated by the answer below, they are handled in the order you defined on your code, but you can impose pre-conditions using middlewares. Take a look at Route handlers (http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) where you use 'next' to pass the control to next function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers (route handlers) are not called *concurrently* (which is what I think you mean with "asynchronously").

They are called in order of their definition, so in your case `blockingController01` will be called for all `GET` requests.

That controller can pass the request along, if the token is correct, to other route handlers that match the URL.

Here's a very basic example of what you're trying to do:

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.query.token !== '12345') {
    // You would use `res.render()` here, this is just a quick demo:
    return res.send(`
      <form>
      Please enter a token and press enter: <input type=text name=token>
      </form>
    `);
  }
  next();
});

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Correct token!</h1>');
});
```

So any `GET` request will hit the first route handler, which checks the validity of the token (in this case, it just checks if the query string parameter `token` has a value of *"12345"*. If not, it will render a form, but if the token matches it will call `next()` which passes the request to the second route handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just as I imagined, then there must be something else in the code interfering (the code exposed was a simplified one). Thanks again.